# Read multiple conversations resources - page size?

Tags: twilio, twilio-conversations

My question is about the following APIs:

- https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-resource#read-multiple-conversation-resources
- https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/service-conversation-resource#read-multiple-service-scoped-conversation-resources

When using the Java SDK for the above APIs, I see an option to specify page-size and limit. Is there any upper bound on the page-size for the above APIs? Or can I simply specify a page-size of 10 million in order to get all conversations in a single request/response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`PageSize` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/twilios-response#response-formats-list-filters) is a default of 50 and a maximum of 1,000. This is set across the Twilio APIs, unless explicitly documented otherwise.